# Запятые перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

Надо ли перед тире обособлять вводное слово "по сути" с двух сторон?

Система управления инженерными данными, по сути, — основной механизм для обмена информацией как внутри предприятия, так и между участниками кооперационной цепочки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном контексте всё же вводное, выражает степень достоверности, запятые нужны, тире факультативно. По правилам не нужно, потому что тире между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится, если между ними есть вводное слово, но если пауза большая, можно поставить как интонационное.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

Тире, даже интонационное, не ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым - существительными, если между ними стоит вводное слово, так как вводное слово в равной мере относится и к подлежащему, и к сказуемому. Именно поэтому тире и убирается по правилу. Пауза между главными членами была бы здесь противоестественна.

Answer (score 1):

Система управления инженерными данными, по сути, основной механизм для обмена информацией как внутри предприятия, так и между участниками кооперационной цепочки.

ПО СУТИ --- вводное слово со значением степени реальности сообщаемого (уверенности). По общему правилу, оно выделяются запятыми. Тире, по общему правилу, здесь не ставится, потому что между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными именами существительными, находится это вводное слово.  Не вижу смысла отступать здесь от существующих правил русской пунктуации.

Answer (score -1):

Либо запятая, либо тире, употребление и запятой и тире - масло масляное.